# Removing "Thank you"'s from questions

Tags: discussion, editing

I have often seen the removal of phrases like "thank you" that mostly newer users, especially 1-rep users, tend to append to their questions.

I even do this myself, mostly because it seems to be a common standard here. I have a speculation why this is done, but want your opinions or a specific reason for it.

In addition: How to justify the changes (in front of the new user) when the main part of the edit is the removal of the "thank you"?

Comment: feel free to edit the title, question and tags as I am quite unfamiliar with meta.

Comment: same on [metase] [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: I mostly reject suggested edits that would still leave a post with serious content or formatting issues as *too minor*. If you bother editing a post, you should fix all of it to the best of your ability.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I (hope I) never edited a question **just** to remove a *Thank you*. But I always take it as a motivation to improve a question.

- I check the title.
  Can it be made more clear? Can it be phrased as a question?
- I check the body of the question.
  Are there typos? Grammatical errors? Wrong capitalization?
- I check the tags.
  Is the question correctly tagged? Missing tags? Non-sensical tags? Maybe even an option for a tag-cleanup?

In my opinion, **only** fixing a *Thanks* in a question sends the wrong signal.

If someone still feels like the majority of an edit was invested in removing a *Thank you* and he complains, I'd explain that we like to keep a high **signal-to-noise ratio**. Meaning, we like it when what we read conveys a lot of information.

While a *Thanks!* can be nice, it distracts from the problem at hand and is simply not necessary.

The SuperUser way of saying *Thank you* is an upvote, and it should be applied to a helpful answer, not be appended to the question itself.

Comment: It makes sense to me to remove excessive personal fluff from a question, but removing such small pleasantries just because they do not contribute specific content, it seems to me, would just change the tone of the SU community to one that is a little less pleasant.

I always end my questions with "Thanks" out of politeness and genuine gratitude for people providing their free time to help me but I noticed today this was edited out (among other changes though).

Is this a deliberate sitewide policy or just some editors' personal preferences? THANKS!

Comment: An upvote is a way of saying thanks only after an answer is posted and it can apply only to those who have actually given an upvote-worthy answer. A "thanks" in the question is a thanks in advance to all who  took the time to help, whether a good answer or not. That seems to me, to be appropriate. IMHO the word(s) "thanks"/"thank you" are totally appropriate and conducive to good community. Removing it is overkill and adds nothing, not even to the clarity of the question.